# Calculation max dates

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to return two max dates from two different columns within the same table. I want the result to be in the same line.
This is my table data:

```
If i have this          
store   item    tran-code   date
1788    2004635    1      17.05.27
1788    2004635    2      17.05.27
1788    2004635   30      17.05.26
1788    2004635    2      17.05.21
1788    2004635    1      17.05.21
1788    2004635    2      17.05.20
1788    2004635    1      17.05.20
```

and i want this…

```
store   item    tran-code   date
1788    2004635    1      17.05.27
1788    2004635    30     17.05.26
```

but if you could get me to return this, it will be perfect

```
store   item      date_1    date_30
1788    2004635  17.05.27   17.05.26
```

where date_1 is the max date for tran-code = 1 and 
date_30 is the max date for tran-code = 30

Comment: what RDBMS and version are you using?

Comment: using SQL Developer

Comment: but what database engine are you using?, Oracle, SQL Server, Postgresql, mysql...?

Comment: using SQL Developer with oracle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use

```
select a.store, a.item, max(a.date) as date_1, t.date_30 
from my_table a 
inner join (
select store, item, max(date) as date_30
from my_table a 
where a.trans-code = 30 
group by store, item
) t on a.store = t.store and a.item = t.item 
group by a.store, a.item, t.date_30
```

Comment: i've tried this and gives error ORA-00937: "not a single-group group function". line 1 column 8. don't know what i'm doing wrong...

Comment: still error, ORA-00979: "not a GROUP BY expression" on line 1 column 52. column 52 matches t.date_30

Answer (score 2):

Use this approach to get the TOP N rows for each partition:

```
SELECT store, item, tran_code, date1 FROM 
(
    SELECT a.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tran_code ORDER BY date1 DESC) rnk FROM tran a
)
WHERE tran_code IN (1,30) AND rnk = 1
```

Another similar use case is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group/52831318#52831318)

Answer (score 1):

If you are selecting only 1 set if store and item, then you can use this. But if you add more store and item, then use join like @scaisEdge's answer.

```
select distinct store,item,
(select max(date) from table1 where tran-code=1) as date_1 
,(select max(date) from table1 where tran-code=30) as date_30
from table1;
```

Comment: i've tried your sugestion and return error: ORA-00923: 
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"

Comment: I put from clause after where, hence the error. Updated. Check now